# putting individual lists on new lines

Tags: python, list

Bloody stupid question from dead brain...

I have a list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

which I sliced up into 3 lists:

```
splits = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
```

which I would like to now have printed on individual lines such that

```
print splits
```

gives

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Can someone please 1) whack me upside the head and 2) remind me how to do this?

Comment: Question is not very clear. Is the list always be 9 items? Are you alwasy want to split it to three sub-lists?

Answer (score 6):

If

```
s = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] # list of lists
```

or

```
s = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]   # a tuple of lists
```

then

```
for i in s:
   print(i)
```

will result in:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Guided by the *[Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)*: Simple is better than complex.

Comment: Thank you. It was gracious of you not to include the slap upside the head. :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the 3 lists a list of lists? ex `[[1],[2],[3]]`?

if so, just:

```
for sliced_list in list_of_lists:
    print(sliced_list)
```

With your given syntax `[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]`, it is a tuple of lists , which will behave the same when using the for statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string join function:

```
print '\n'.join(str(x) for x in [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your first quesion.

For the second one, you might like to do it like:

```
>>> splits = [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
>>> print "\n".join([repr(item) for item in splits])
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
```